# Store Docker images in a root file system without running a Docker daemon

Tags: docker

Is there a way to store Docker images in Dockers internal (e.g. overlayfs2) storage format without using Docker daemon itself? The use case is to pre-install a Docker image onto a root file system without having too many dependencies.

I use skopeo quite a bit, and it has support for "containers-storage:" repository type. This repository type gets configured through `storage.conf`, which has a overlayfs driver. However, is this the same overlayfs format as used in Docker (the ones stored under `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the docker image as a tar file
`docker save [docker image] > filename.tar`

Comment: I am aware of `docker save` but that only stores a container (via the docker daemon) in a tarball. What I want is restoring/downloading and storing in Dockers storage backend without running the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 ~ $ skopeo copy docker://docker.io/library/alpine:latest containers-storage:localhost/alpine:latest
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 89d9c30c1d48 done
Copying config 965ea09ff2 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures

 ~ $ buildah images -a
REPOSITORY         TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
localhost/alpine   latest   965ea09ff2eb   3 weeks ago   5.82 MB
```

Comment: Yes, this works with `buildah` and other tools which make use of the github.com/containers/storage library (e.g. `podman`). However, it does not work for Docker from what I understand.